# please suggest me the best practice in sting-value formating

Tags: python, django, pep

i have a long string like below which i m trying to format aswel aligning it with PEP standards

```
'http://abc/api/run=1&'+ \
            'actionData=[{"query":"air-{0}-{1}-{2}--1-0-0-E-111--"},{"query":"hotels-{1}-{3}-{4}-1-1_0-"},{"query":"air-{1}-{0}-{5}--1-0-0-E-111--"}]'+ \
            '&tripOrigin={0}&tripDestination={1}'.format(origin.get('vcid'), destination.get('vcid'), onward_f_date, check_in_date, check_out_date, return_f_date)
```

But ran in to output like be this

```
'http://abc/api/run=1&actionData=[{"query":"air-{0}-{1}-{2}--1-0-0-E-111--"},{"query":"hotels-{1}-{3}-{4}-1-1_0-"},{"query":"air-{1}-{0}-{5}--1-0-0-E-111--"}]&tripOrigin=2311443&tripDestination=123445667'
```

expecting formatting happen all the {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4} and {5}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the curly braces that don't correspond to formatting placeholders.

Eg: 
This

```
'actionData=[{"query":"air-{0}-{1}-{2}--1-0-0-E-111--"}
```

Should look like:

```
'actionData=[{{"query":"air-{0}-{1}-{2}--1-0-0-E-111--"}}
```

So:

```
>>> print 'http://abc/api/run=1&actionData=[{{"query":"air-{0}-{1}-{2}--1-0-0-E-111--"}},{{"query":"hotels-{1}-{3}-{4}-1-1_0-"}},{{"query":"air-{1}-{0}-{5}--1-0-0-E-111--"}}]&
tripOrigin={0}&tripDestination={1}'.format(999,999,999,999,999,999)

http://abc/api/run=1&actionData=[{"query":"air-999-999-999--1-0-0-E-111--"},{"query":"hotels-999-999-999-1-1_0-"},{"query":"air-999-999-999--1-0-0-E-111--"}]&tripOrigin=999&tripDestination=999
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use concatenation: use the implicit joining that happens inside parentheses.

```
my_string = (
    'http://abc/api/run=1&'
    'actionData=[{"query":"air-{0}-{1}-{2}--1-0-0-E-111--"},{"query":"hotels-{1}-{3}-{4}-1-1_0-"},{"query":"air-{1}-{0}-{5}--1-0-0-E-111--"}]'
    '&tripOrigin={0}&tripDestination={1}'.format(origin.get('vcid'), destination.get('vcid'), onward_f_date, check_in_date, check_out_date, return_f_date)
)
```

Comment: hi @Daniel : ending up with this error KeyError: '"query"'

Answer (score 1):

Surround your string with parentheses, you also won't need the + and \ anymore:

```
('http://abc/api/run=1&'
 'actionData=[{"query":"air-{0}-{1}-{2}--1-0-0-E-111--"},{"query":"hotels-{1}-{3}-{4}-1-1_0-"},{"query":"air-{1}-{0}-{5}--1-0-0-E-111--"}]'
 '&tripOrigin={0}&tripDestination={1}').format(origin.get('vcid'), destination.get('vcid'), onward_f_date, check_in_date, check_out_date, return_f_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_string = (
    'http://abc/api/run=1&'
    'actionData=[{"query":"air-{0}-{1}-{2}--1-0-0-E-111--"},'
    '{"query":"hotels-{1}-{3}-{4}-1-1_0-"},'
    '{"query":"air-{1}-{0}-{5}--1-0-0-E-111--"}]'
    '&tripOrigin={0}&tripDestination={1}'
).format(origin.get('vcid'), destination.get('vcid'),
         onward_f_date, check_in_date, check_out_date, return_f_date)
```